# Swift webView empty spaces on scroll

Tags: swift, webview

When I'm scrolling up or down and no space for scroll, there are empty spaces. How can I fix it?

[image: top scrolling]

[image: botton scrolling]

Empty places I marked with a red lines.

code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let aurl = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")

        let arequest = URLRequest(url: aurl!)

        webView.loadRequest(arequest)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it.

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```